# reference error:jw player is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jwplayer, thickbox

I'm showing the jw player inside the thickbox and calling the jwplayer code through ajax. When I call it, it is showing the thickbox without jwplayer and Error console showing the reference error "jwplayer is not defined" error.I'm using the jquery 1.8 .When I call it 2nd time without page refresh it is showing the video inside the jwplayer and error console showing no error.I'm using the following code.plz let me know how can I fix it?

```
$.ajax {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'modules/oneclickorder.php?divid=' + DIVID,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $("#oneclickorder1").html(data);
        tb_show('Welcome', '#TB_inline?height=700&amp;width=550&inlineId=' + DIVID + '&modal=true', null);
    }
})
```

oneclickorder.php page code

```
 echo '<div id="testvideo"  style="display:none";>
 <div id="playvideo" style="width:549px;height:550px; background-color:#FFF;"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.markettrendsignal.com/js/jwplayer.js">   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("playvideo").setup({
  flashplayer: "https://www.markettrendsignal.com/js/player.swf",
  file:"reversalpatternsplugin.flv",
        height: 330,
        provider: "rtmp",
        streamer: "rtmp://s2qwctg3okfahu.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
        width: 550,
     autostart:true
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: show us a (non)working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

It's acting that way because the js file for jwplayer isn't loaded when you execute the script the first time.

Here's a breakdown of what's happening.

When you first call the ajax function, you return the HTML code which will download the .js file and execute the javascript code. Problem is, it executes the code before the file is loaded. Remember this is injecting javascript... there is no document.ready... you're already passed that.

The second time you call the function it works because the .js file is already loaded (from the first time).

**Solution:** Add the js file in the main document.

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins/content/jw_allvideos/jw_allvideos/includes/js/wmvplayer/silverlight.js
```

Copy All code
Change the encoding to ANSI
Paste all code, and save.